# How will I make an alert box that shows a password protect of a page?

Tags: javascript, html

How will I combine my `window.onload` on my `function pw()`?

```
function pw(){
    var password = 1;
    var lbl = prompt('Please Enter Your Password',' ');
    while (password < 3) {
        if (!password) 
        history.go(-1);
        if (password.toLowerCase() == "1234") {
            window.open('/about');
            break;
            } 
    password+=1;
    var lbl = prompt('Access Denied');
    }
    if (lbl.toLowerCase()!="password" & password ==3) 
    history.go(-1);
    return " ";
}
```

You may say that I don't have my `window.onload` code, its because I don't have idea on how will I write it. The program goes like this, when a menu in the navigation is clicked, I want an alert box showing the password protect(`function pw()`), if the user correctly input the password, the content of the page is shown, if not, the user will be redirected to the homepage of the site or the previous page the user viewed.

Comment: Anyone can view the JavaScript included on your page to find out that they'd need to enter a password of "1234".

Comment: why dont you just use htaccess and htpasswd for this? - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html

Comment: so you are saying, it is impossible to have a secure password page with just html and js??? are there no other ways to to do the password page w/o involving the server side? @KaiQing

Comment: depends on the level of security you want. If you don't care that anyone could view source and get the password you have clearly defined in the code then js and html only is fine. Otherwise, server side is the only way I know of unless there's some kind of service you could call via ajax. All that would mean is the server side handling would be on someone else and not you so basically the answer is still no.

Comment: how about javascript encryption??? @KaiQing

Comment: bottom line is javascript is client side. No matter what kind of encryption you use, it is still public and those who care to decrypt it have everything they need to do so. Is there a reason why you want to avoid server restrictions? Or are you just curious if it is possible to do it with js alone?

Comment: just curious if js can do it alone, because I know already about the server side in having the password security, someone just said to me that it is possible because javascript offers this encryption thing. 
thank you so much by the way @KaiQing